# Gridview: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to get the value from my gridview depending on the row I select.
I am getting the error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

```
   protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        } 

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged"  
 autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>

  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_ID" HeaderText="ID" Visible=false/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Pay_Dt" HeaderText="Pay Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}"    

    HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-Width="100" HeaderStyle-BorderColor=navy ItemStyle-BorderColor="navy" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Emp_Name" HeaderText="Employee Name" ItemStyle-Width="250" HeaderStyle-BorderColor=navy ItemStyle-BorderColor="navy" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Emp_Num" HeaderText="Number" ItemStyle-Width="75" HeaderStyle-BorderColor=navy ItemStyle-BorderColor="navy" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Emp_Dept" HeaderText="Department" ItemStyle-Width="100" HeaderStyle-BorderColor=navy ItemStyle-BorderColor="navy" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Pay_End_Dt" HeaderText="Pay End Date" Visible="false" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Net_Amt" HeaderText="Net Amount" ItemStyle-Width="150" HeaderStyle-BorderColor=navy ItemStyle-BorderColor="navy" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Total_Earnings1" HeaderText="Total Earnings1" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Total_Earnings2" HeaderText="Total Earnings2" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Total_Taxes1" HeaderText="Total Taxes1" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Total_Taxes2" HeaderText="Total Taxes2" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Total_Deductions1" HeaderText="Total Deductions1" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Total_Deductions2" HeaderText="Total Deductions2" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Net_Pay1" HeaderText="Net Pay1" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Net_Pay2" HeaderText="Net Pay2" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Vac_Hrs" HeaderText="Vacation Hours" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Sck_Hrs" HeaderText="Sick Hours" Visible="false" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Batch_Num" HeaderText="Batch Number" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Load_Count" HeaderText="Load Count" Visible="false"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ESS_Load_Dt" HeaderText="Load Date" Visible="false"/>
    <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="150" />  
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: once again a simple `Google Search` could have helped you to solve this there are so many working examples out there for this ..

Answer (score 0):

you appear to be in the wrong EventHandler try the following example

```
private void GridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (GridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
   {
     int selectedrowindex = GridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
     DataGridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];  
     name = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["Cell Zero's Name goes here"].Value);           
   }
}
```

if you are going to use the `name` local variable outside of this method then `string name` needs 
to be declared outside the local scope

for example at the class level declare it as the following then you can use it globally

```
public static string name = string.Empty;
```

Some additional Methods / Events you can checkout as well [DataGrid.SelectedItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I just merely need to get the variable on the selected row without calling the event.

Comment: so where in your code do you want to do this..? why are you trying to avoid using the Event to do this..? are you going to come up with your own Method to check this for example in the `Page_Load` event..? please explain this you could do this by checking the `GridView`.SelectRow` and do the opposite of what `Smola` has posted as an answer...